# How to get the un-filtered rows in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, record

I have a doubt with filtering. SO, I have a data set based on the condition. Now based on the condtion I get the filtered record buts also I want unfiltered data how do we get it?

Code:

```
df =

  a   b   c
0 1   2   3
1 21  02  1
2 18  03  2
3 20  1   1
4 1   1   18
5 0   0   1
filter = 'a>1 and c<3'
df.query(filter)
```

output for this:

```
a   b   c
1 21  02  1
2 18  03  2
3 20  1   1
```

Now I want the other records as well. How do we get the unfiltered records?

Excepted Output:

```
a   b   c
0 1   2   3
4 1   1   18
5 0   0   1
```

Comment: Haven't tested it yet but something on the lines of `df_unfiltered = df[df != df.query(filter)]`

Comment: @jojo_040 tried it gettin an error ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a quick pseudo/theoretical attempt - I've posted an answer with the correct solution. :)

Comment: Seeing as my answer has solved your issue would mind marking it as the answer + give it an upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I recreate your dataframe and create the desired subset dataframe based on your condition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,21,18,20,1,0],
'b':[2,2,3,1,1,0],
'c':[3,1,2,1,18,1]})

filter = 'a>1 and c<3'
df_subset = df.query(filter)
```

Then we merge the subset on the original, we filter out for the unmerged values and drop the column `_merge`

```
df_1 = df.merge(df_subset, how='left', indicator=True)
df_1 = df_1[df_1['_merge'] == 'left_only']
df_1.drop(['_merge'],axis=1, inplace = True)
```

this gives you your desired output, represented by dataframe `df_1`:

[image]

Or you can simply filter post merge and not drop the column, i.e.

```
df_1 = df.merge(df_subset, how='left', indicator=True)
df_1[df_1['_merge'] == 'left_only'][['a','b','c']]
```